# BackBone & Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a problem with adding a second Collection to my Backbone/Rails project

Here is my class file for the Collection companies

```
class Raffler.Collections.Companies extends Backbone.Collection
  url: '/api/companies'
  model: Raffler.Models.Company
```

Here's the Class file for the Model

```
class Raffler.Models.Company extends Backbone.Model
```

Heres' the Router

```
class Raffler.Routers.Companies extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    'companies': 'index'
    'companies/:id' : 'show'

  initialize: ->
    @companies = new Raffler.Collections.Companies()
    @companies.fetch()
    alert @companies

  index: ->
    view = new Raffler.Views.CompaniesIndex(collection: @companies)
    $('#container').html(view.render().el)
```

And here is the view

```
class Raffler.Views.CompaniesIndex extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['companies/index']

  initialize: ->
    @companies.on('reset', @render, this)

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(companies: @companies))
    this
```

It falls over when I get to `@companies.on` - the error is Cannot call method 'on' on undefined.

I don't understand this error - I have set the `@companies` as the Collection in the router and passed it into the view that is created in the router class.

I have the exact same code implemented on another collection in the application, so I'm wondering is it because I am trying to add a second collection?

It all works perfectly within the javascript console in the browser when I do the following

```
companies = new Raffler.Collection.Companies()
companies.fetch()
companies.length
```

I can see that it is making the call to the server and returning the correct number of records - so why doesn't the code work within the application?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your router, you say this:

```
view = new Raffler.Views.CompaniesIndex(collection: @companies)
```

That will set the [`@collection` property](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-constructor) of the new CompaniesIndex to `@companies`:

> There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: [...] `collection` [...].

So in your view, you should refer to `@collection`, not `@companies`:

```
class Raffler.Views.CompaniesIndex extends Backbone.View
  #...
  initialize: ->
    @collection.on('reset', @render, @)
```

`@companies` is only defined inside the router, the view only knows about `@collection` unless you explicitly assign something to `@companies` inside the view.